# Strange question on the justification behind sets and ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been asked to explain the reasoning for defining sets as unordered collections of distinct elements, and sequences as ordered collections of possibly identical elements, and most strangely: could I justify defining a new set that's somewhere in the middle (an ordered collection of distinct elements).

For the first part, I've said that in sets, we care only about what objects we have in the set, so the order in which they appear doesn't matter (because it doesn't affect the content of the set), nor does the number of elements we have.

For the second part, I've said that ordered collections can be used to define sequences and in combinatorics, where order matters and an element can be repeated more than once.

For the third part, I have no idea.

My reasons feel a bit hand-wavy and honestly, seem to just restate the properties of sets and ordered collections.

Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that the whole thing is hand-wavy to begin with. So you shouldn't feel bad about this, it seems like one of these questions assigned only so the students will try to contemplate on nature of sets and sequences and the difference between them.

Sets come to model a collection of objects. If I want to look at how many members my immediate family has, that's a set. Specifying my mom six times won't make me have six moms, and saying my brother's name before my sister's name has literally no difference. Sets, similarly, have no interest in repetition or order.

Sequences come to model the line to an awesome arcade machine (think Street Fighter Alpha 2) where you can buy preassigned game time. Since the game is awesome I bought six games in a row, and only because I wasn't fast enough, six other people will play before my seventh game. The list of who gets to play and in what order is a sequence. It is entirely order dependent, and repetition does matter. Because dammit, I have to wait for 12 games now by three guys before I get to go again.

Finally, in between you can find multisets which are order-insensitive collections which allow repetitions; and sequences which do not allow repetitions. I will let you think about the nature of those on your own.

Comment: Thanks! Is simply giving an application of sequences enough to justify their existence? Also, I'm not looking for something unordered; I'm looking for an ordered collection of distinct elements, but I can't seem to justify creating such a thing. Maybe it could be used in priority queues to determine which processes in a computer have priority? You might have the same process appearing multiple times, but the order in which this happens is important.

Comment: I don't know what you are supposed to answer. I would not have asked my students this question, unless I would have had a discussion with them about this, sowing the seeds to the possible answers. So I can only answer what I would have said to my students. I don't even remotely know what does it actually mean to justify the existence of a mathematical object, other than to explain what it should model, as an idea.

Comment: Haha, okay. Is there a name for the object that has the properties that I'm looking for (an ordered collection of distinct elements)?

Comment: Injective sequence, I'd guess. Or an ordered set maybe.